# Not numeric atoms LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to ask why this function doesn't work...

```
(defun nenum(ls)
  (cond
   ((null ls) nil)
   ((listp car(ls)) (nenum (rest ls))) 
   ((numberp car(ls)) (nenum (rest ls)))
   (t (cons (car ls) (nenum (rest ls))))))
```

Example: `(nenum '(l 1 i (b) (5) s -2 p)) --> (l i s p)`

Thank you!

Comment: For starters car(ls) is a syntax error. You also haven't explained what you want the function to do. Just gave one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `car(ls)` with `(car ls)`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the predicate you have in one of your cond terms:

```
(listp car (ls))
```

Thus apply the function `listp` with the two arguments `car` and the result of calling the function `ls` with no arguments. `car` and `ls` both need to be free variables and `listp` needs to be a different function than the one [defined in CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_listp.htm) since it only takes one argument.

Perhaps you have though you were writing Algol? An Algol function call look like `operator(operand)` but not CL. CL is a LISP dialect and we have this form on our function calls:

```lisp
(operand operator)
```

If we nest we do the same:

```lisp
(operand (operand operator))
```

You got it right in the alternative `(cons (car ls) (nenum (rest ls)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much easier way to write that function:

```
(defun nenum (list)
   (remove-if (lambda (item)
                  (or (listp item)
                      (numberp item)))
              list))
```

Note that `NIL` doesn't need its own test because `listp` covers it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write a function like this from scratch.  Common Lisp already provides **remove-if**, and you can give it a predicate that matches numbers and non-atoms:

```
CL-USER> (remove-if #'(lambda (x)
                        (or (numberp x)
                            (not (atom x))))
                    '(l 1 i (b) (5) s -2 p))
;=> (L I S P)
```

Or, to make it even clearer that you're keeping non-numeric atoms, you can use **remove-if-not** with a predicate that checks for numeric atoms:

```
CL-USER> (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x)
                            (and (atom x)
                                 (not (numberp x))))
                        '(l 1 i (b) (5) s -2 p))
;=> (L I S P)
```

Note that the empty list, which is often *written* as **()**, is just the *symbol* **nil**.  As such, it too is a non-numeric atom.  If you'd want to keep other symbols, e.g.,

```
CL-USER> (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x)
                            (and (atom x)
                                 (not (numberp x))))
                        '(li (b) -1 (5) sp))
;=> (LI SP)
```

then you'll probably want to keep **nil** as well:

```
CL-USER> (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x)
                            (and (atom x)
                                 (not (numberp x))))
                        '(van (b) () (5) a))
;=> (VAN NIL A)
```

Comment: Your version won't remove `NIL` because `(atom nil)` = `T`

Comment: @throwaway The title said "not numeric atoms". I'd say the listp in OP's code is a bug.